# GAE find entities with item not in ListProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a little application where I am passing messages between users. My model for the message is like this

```
class Message(db.Model):
    from = db.UserProperty()
    sent_to_users = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

I send the message to users if they are online, so when I detect that a user is online I send any message that has not already been sent to them. I do `message.sent_to_users.append(user)`  in the [/chat/presence/available handler](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/overview.html#Handling_User_Presence). To indicate that a message has already been sent to `user`

My question is how do I filter out messages that have already been sent to a user. According to the section on [inequality filter in queries](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Overview) a `!=` translates to two queries for greater than and lesser than and the results are then combined. Which needless to say does not work in the case of a list of Keys. Basically `members_not_sent_message = Message.all().filter('sent_to_users !=', available_user).fetch(100)` does not work.

Is there a way to find values not in a ListProperty, or do I have to go through each item and find messages which have not been sent? Or is there another design for a system like this that circumvents this GAE datastore limitation (if there is one in this case) ?

Comment: No, there is no good way to do this. Each item in the ListProperty is indexed separately.

Comment: If I was implementing this, I would store the undelivered messages by user. It might result in more storage, but I think it'll make the code much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inequality filters on list properties don't really work. As you know, inequality filters run separate "less than value" and "greater than value" queries under the hood, and then concatenate the results. List properties with multiple values will have multiple hits in the same index, so if you filter out one item you'll always match another.

Consider keeping two lists: besides the `sent` list, keep a `not_sent` list, and query that.

Comment: Accepting this answer since its closest to what I've wound up doing. I have added a list of messages to be sent for each user and I remove the message from the list (or queue) once the message is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one http://nick.zoic.org/art/python/multiple_inequalities/ ?

Comment: That is for inequalities using multiple properties. I want to check for a certain value that does not exist in a ListProperty. `!=` does not seem to work on a single ListProperty.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can't do this query. You shouldn't be using a ListProperty to track anything that can grow unbounded, though, such as unread messages, as there are hard limits on how big a ListProperty can get. Instead, you should have a flag on the messages themselves that indicates if they've been sent/read.

Comment: 5000 limit on ListProperty size to be precise. It seems that 5000 is a magic number for Google when it is about limiting something... must be their BigTable constraint...